# How to asssign a value to a global variable from ajax output

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
var temp_f;

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/a5fb7d26008efccb/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/India/Dhule.json",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(parsed_json) {
            var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
            temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
            alert("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + h);
        }
    });
});

function get(){
    alert(temp_f);  
}
```

I want to store value of local variable `temp_f` in jQuery section into global variable `temp_f` declared at the beginning of script but when I am running this code it is showing value of global `temp_f` as `undefined`.

Can anyone point out the mistake I am making or suggest any other way to do so?

Comment: Please take the time to format your code before asking people to read it (in truth you should never have badly formatted code, but as long as you don't show it, that's just being a bad coder, not being rude).

Comment: When the get() method is called ?

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `get()` after the AJAX request has completed?

Comment: You need to show us when you're trying to call `get()`, also is your alert inside of your `success` firing properly?

Comment: 1. Do you actually call `get()` at the end of the success handler?
2. Are you sure that the value of `parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f']` is really defined? (else the value of `temp_f` would rightfully be `undefined`

Comment: As an alternative to `get` firing too soon, you mention _"**local** variable `temp_f`"_ - is this _all_ the relevant code, or are you perhaps redeclaring `temp_f` within the `ready` callback scope?

Comment: This question's answer depends on "where" is the get() method called !!